# Помогите с программой для тестирования

Tags: c#, winforms

Пишу прогу, которая проводит тестирование. Когда выбран правильный ответ подгружает следующий вопрос, если неправильный, то просто выкидает окно о ошибке и увеличивает счетчик. Перед этим написал прогу которая считывает эти самые вопросы и картинку в txt в виде:

```
Номер вопроса
Вопрос
Вариант 1
Вариант 2
Вариант 3
Вариант 4
Вариант 5
Правильный ответ (от 1 до 5)
Путь к картинке (C:\Users\Бодя\Pictures\Saved Pictures\Новый точечный рисунок.bmp)
```

Сам код программы который у меня получился:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int НеправильнихВідповідей = 0;
    string ВибранаВідповідь , ПравильнаВідповідь;

    System.IO.StreamReader Читатель;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ПочатокТесту();

    }

    void ПочатокТесту()
    {
        var Кодировка = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1251);
        Читатель = new System.IO.StreamReader(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\test.txt", Кодировка);
        while (Читатель.EndOfStream == false)
        {
            label4.Text = Читатель.ReadLine();
            label5.Text = Читатель.ReadLine();
            // Создание экземпляра StreamReader для чтения из файла

            button3.Text = Читатель.ReadLine();
            button4.Text = Читатель.ReadLine();
            button5.Text = Читатель.ReadLine();
            button6.Text = Читатель.ReadLine();
            button7.Text = Читатель.ReadLine();
            ПравильнаВідповідь = Читатель.ReadLine();
            pictureBox2.ImageLocation = Читатель.ReadLine();
            if (ВибранаВідповідь == ПравильнаВідповідь) { MessageBox.Show("Вірно"); ПочатокТесту(); }
            else { MessageBox.Show("Спробуй ще"); НеправильнихВідповідей++; }
        }
        Читатель.Close();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ВибранаВідповідь = "1";
    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ВибранаВідповідь = "3";
    }

    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ВибранаВідповідь = "4";
    }

    private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ВибранаВідповідь = "5";
    }

    private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void label5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ВибранаВідповідь = "2";
    }
}
```

[image: Такой вот вид должен быть]

Ошибка в том, что оно не подгружает информацию с файла и вообще не работает. Прошу помощи

Comment: Ну вы читаете ваши варианты в виде текста, а правильный читаете в виде цифры (как я понял).

Comment: А, все, дошло. А что именно не работает? У вас в файлике могут быть лишние пробелы в какой-то из строчек. Они тоже являются символами, да-да. (Мой мозг реально взрывается от новых ощущений). А ещё, вам не следует использовать в коде украинский кроме как для строк. Ибо сейчас оно компилируется, а потом какие-нибудь проблемы с кодировкой возникнут. Нехорошо это. Не православно)

Comment: А ещё у вас читается из файла в цикле. И вы вызываете внутри цикла этот метод ещё раз, если ответ правильный. В итоге рекурсия. Тоже нехорошо. Тут вообще наверно все нужно переписывать)

Comment: будет проще считать все вопросы из файла в список, а потом уже работать с ним

Comment: ничего не помогло

Comment: В формах событийная модель, не получится просто взять код консольной программы и просто заменить операции ввода/вывода. Перенесите `if` из метода отображения вопроса в обработчики кнопок и при правильном ответе там же повторно вызывайте метод отображения следующего вопроса. И да, замените украинский на нормальный английский, хоть бы и транслит, читать код тяжело.